# Boolean if statement for multiple events plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have problem with Boolean `flag`.

There is no problem if there's just one button, but with multiple buttons it's problematic. After first click the value of the `flag` is `false`. But to change the second button's arrow the `flag` value `true` value  is needed... and so on...

Please click every button one after another to see what I mean.

How can I solve this issue?

```js
  var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.cdi-link');
  var flag = true;

  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      var button = this;
      var arrow = button.lastElementChild.lastElementChild;

      if (flag) {
        flag = false;
        arrow.innerHTML = '&#9660;';
        console.log(flag);
      } else {
        flag = true;
        arrow.innerHTML = '&#9654;';
        console.log(flag);
      }
    });
  }
```

```html
          
    <button type="button" class="cdi-link">
      <div>
        <span>click to change the arrow</span> <span class="arrow">&#9654;</span>
      </div>
    </button>
          
    <button type="button" class="cdi-link">
      <div>
        <span>click to change the arrow</span> <span class="arrow">&#9654;</span>
      </div>
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="cdi-link">
      <div>
        <span>click to change the arrow</span> <span class="arrow">&#9654;</span>
      </div>
    </button>
```

Comment: So you want every button to have its own flag?

Comment: You need more than one flag, one per button.

Comment: Creating an IIFE in a loop should be seen as a *last resort* solution. For some reason, it's the first thing people reach for, but it's often very unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a closure over the flag by using a function which creates an own scope for `flag`.

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.cdi-link');

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener('click', function (flag) {
        return function () {
            var button = this;
            var arrow = button.lastElementChild.lastElementChild;

            if (flag) {
                flag = false;
                arrow.innerHTML = '&#9660;';
                console.log(flag);
            } else {
                flag = true;
                arrow.innerHTML = '&#9654;';
                console.log(flag);
            }
        };
    }(true)); // start value for flag
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="cdi-link"><div><span>click to change the arrow</span> <span class="arrow">&#9654;</span></div></button>
<button type="button" class="cdi-link"><div><span>click to change the arrow</span> <span class="arrow">&#9654;</span></div></button>
<button type="button" class="cdi-link"><div><span>click to change the arrow</span> <span class="arrow">&#9654;</span></div></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either associate state with each button, or in this case you could simply toggle a class.

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.cdi-link');
  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('cdi-link--open');
    });
  }
```

```css
.cdi-link .arrow::after {
  content: "▲";
 }
 
 .cdi-link--open .arrow::after {
  content: "▼";
 }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="cdi-link">
    <div>
      <span>click to change the arrow</span> <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
  </button>

  <button type="button" class="cdi-link">
    <div>
      <span>click to change the arrow</span> <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
  </button>

  <button type="button" class="cdi-link">
    <div>
      <span>click to change the arrow</span> <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
  </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to store an individual `flag` inside each button using `this.flag` :

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.cdi-link');


  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      var button = this
      var arrow = button.lastElementChild.lastElementChild;
      
      if (this.flag) {
        this.flag = false;
        arrow.innerHTML = '&#9654;';
      } else {
        this.flag = true;
        arrow.innerHTML = '&#9660;';
      }
      console.log("Flag = " + this.flag);
    });
  }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="cdi-link">
      <div>
        <span>click to change the arrow</span> <span class="arrow">&#9654;</span>
      </div>
    </button>
          
    <button type="button" class="cdi-link">
      <div>
        <span>click to change the arrow</span> <span class="arrow">&#9654;</span>
      </div>
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="cdi-link">
      <div>
        <span>click to change the arrow</span> <span class="arrow">&#9654;</span>
      </div>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple and put a property directly on the element (because you're just storing primitive data anyway). Just be sure to give it a name that won't likely conlict with any other code.

```js
  var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.cdi-link');

  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].__my_flag__ = true;
    btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      var button = this;
      var arrow = button.lastElementChild.lastElementChild;

      if (button.__my_flag__) {
        button.__my_flag__ = false;
        arrow.innerHTML = '&#9660;';
        console.log(button.__my_flag__);
      } else {
        button.__my_flag__ = true;
        arrow.innerHTML = '&#9654;';
        console.log(button.__my_flag__);
      }
    });
  }
```

```html
          
    <button type="button" class="cdi-link">
      <div>
        <span>click to change the arrow</span> <span class="arrow">&#9654;</span>
      </div>
    </button>
          
    <button type="button" class="cdi-link">
      <div>
        <span>click to change the arrow</span> <span class="arrow">&#9654;</span>
      </div>
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="cdi-link">
      <div>
        <span>click to change the arrow</span> <span class="arrow">&#9654;</span>
      </div>
    </button>
```

This is memory safe, even in old browsers, and uses less memory overhead than closure solutions, which actually ***do*** sometimes have memory leak problems in old browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).
Declare `flag` inside IIFE to create self executing block in each iteration of `for` loop. Try the following:

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.cdi-link');

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  (function(){
    var flag = true;
    btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      var button = this;
      var arrow = button.lastElementChild.lastElementChild;

      if (flag) {
        flag = false;
        arrow.innerHTML = '&#9660;';
        console.log(flag);
      } else {
        flag = true;
        arrow.innerHTML = '&#9654;';
        console.log(flag);
      }
    });
  })();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="cdi-link">
      <div>
        <span>click to change the arrow</span> <span class="arrow">&#9654;</span>
      </div>
    </button>
          
    <button type="button" class="cdi-link">
      <div>
        <span>click to change the arrow</span> <span class="arrow">&#9654;</span>
      </div>
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="cdi-link">
      <div>
        <span>click to change the arrow</span> <span class="arrow">&#9654;</span>
      </div>
    </button>
```